# Query many values into one request - entity framework

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework-core, request, combine

i am new to the entity framework.
i want so find a spezific database item...

i used this code

```
using (var db = new DatabaseX(_connectionVar))
            {
                try
                {
                    var data = from test in db.X where test.Y== Y && test.z== z && test.s== s select test;

                }
            }
```

but how can i combine this parameters? With the sign "&&" it doesn´t work...

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: *What* "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you are using entity framework you first want to make a db context: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext.
Then you want to make some sort of repository where you can get your data:

```
return await dbContext.test
            .Where(test => test.X == X)
            .Where(test => test.Y == Y)
            .Where(test => test.Z == Z)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

But reading and following the fundamentals on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/ should be a big help.

Comment: As for EF that's the same as `&&`. It will generate the same query.